# What is a good resource to understand "Branch Cut".

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

I read the book of J B Conway for Complex Analysis. I don't have clear concept about "**Branch Point**" and "**branch cut**" of an analytic function. And this topic is not discussed in Conway's book elaborately ...So its too hard to understand it from this book.

So can anyone here please suggest me a good book (or any pdf) from which I can understand this concept. Thank you.

Comment: The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts) on the topic is quite good in my opinion.

Comment: Okay....and any book..??

Comment: I have only read Gamelin's Complex Analysis, so that is the only book that I can really recommend.

Comment: Thank you........

Comment: If I recall correctly the book "Lectures on Riemann Surfaces" by Otto Forster contains quite a lot about these things.

Answer (score 1):

Tristan Needham's award-winning book *Visual Complex Analysis* explains in detail at an undergraduate level.

Answer (score 0):

You can read Complex Variables and Application by J. W. Brown & R. V. Churchill, in the book the topic is discussed with a few examples though in not much details but a fair amount to get basic ideas.